# How to create a loop for caching images by AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have 100 movieclip on the stage, named ads_box_1 ... ads_box_100.there is another movieclip in each ads_box, named photo_box.I want cache 100 images(1.jpg,2.jpg,...,100.jpg) from server and add them to each ads_box.photo_box.I try some loops to do that,but they didn't work.So what is the solution?this my code:

```
import org.sgmnt.lib.net.*;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.filesystem.File;
for (var i:Number=1; i<=5; i++)
{
    this["ads_box_" + i].photo_box.alpha = 0;
}
LocalCacheSettings.WORKING_DIRECTORY = File.applicationStorageDirectory;
//how to create a loop frome here...
var pic_loader:Loader;
NetClassFactory.initialize( LocalCacheLoader, LocalCacheURLLoader, LocalCacheNetStream );
pic_loader = NetClassFactory.createLoader();
pic_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, _onComplete );
var pic_string:String = "http://localhost/Pics/" + String(1) + ".jpg";
pic_loader.load( new URLRequest(pic_string));
function _onComplete(e:Event):void
{
    var new_pic_mc:Sprite= new Sprite();
    new_pic_mc.addChild(pic_loader);
    new_pic_mc.width = new_pic_mc.height = 90;
    this["ads_box_" + 1].photo_box.addChild(new_pic_mc);
    this["ads_box_" + 1].photo_box.alpha = 1;
}
//to here
```

Comment: You need to load the images from the application storage directory and not local host. I'm assuming you have the images saved there, or you are asking how to save the images there?

Comment: @GurtejSingh thanks, but my code works perfectly for 1 image and there is no problem.local host is for test only.I want do that for 100 images.how to do that?

Comment: Instead of doing a loop maintain a counter and create a method to load the image which accepts a count value. Increment the count by 1 each time a load finishes and load the next image. Do this until count is 100. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is that something you are looking for?

Comment: @GurtejSingh,thanks. yes exactly, but I don't know how to do that ! :(

Comment: but then your question is related to caching. all the loop is going to do is load the images and add them. i am assuming you will either update your question, or add the caching logic yourself?

Comment: @GurtejSingh my Q is about loop.how to create a loop to cache 100 images. I use this (https://github.com/sgmnt/LocalCacheLoader) to chaching images.but I don`t know to create the loop! sorry for my bad English.

Comment: No problem. If your caching is already being handled, then you can see an example in my answer as to how to create the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this, note that this just loads the images in a sequential loop. You should also add event listeners for error handling. You will have to write the caching logic on top of this:

```
import org.sgmnt.lib.net.*;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.filesystem.File;
for (var i:Number=1; i<=5; i++)
{
    this["ads_box_" + i].photo_box.alpha = 0;
}
LocalCacheSettings.WORKING_DIRECTORY = File.applicationStorageDirectory;
//how to create a loop frome here...
var pic_loader:Loader;
NetClassFactory.initialize( LocalCacheLoader, LocalCacheURLLoader, LocalCacheNetStream );
pic_loader = NetClassFactory.createLoader();
pic_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, _onComplete );
var currentImageCount:uint = 1;
//load the first image
loadImage();

function loadImage():void
{
    var pic_string:String = "http://localhost/Pics/" + String(currentImageCount) + ".jpg";
    pic_loader.load( new URLRequest(pic_string));
}

function _onComplete(e:Event):void
{
    var new_pic_mc:Sprite= new Sprite();
    new_pic_mc.addChild(pic_loader);
    new_pic_mc.width = new_pic_mc.height = 90;
    this["ads_box_" + currentImageCount].photo_box.addChild(new_pic_mc);
    this["ads_box_" + currentImageCount].photo_box.alpha = 1;
    //WRITE YOUR CACHING LOGIC HERE FOR EACH LOADED IMAGE
    if (currentImageCount <= 100)
    {
        currentImageCount++;
        loadImage();
    }
    else
    {
        pic_loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, _onComplete);
    }
}
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: yesssss! by some little changes, your code works very nice :) Thank you man :)

Comment: @Fanous glad I could be of any help. Thanks for posting the working code, however you may want to avoid creating new instances of loader every time and also avoid adding event listeners every time. Could get performance heavy. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

and finally this code works nice,thanks @Gurtej Singh

```
import org.sgmnt.lib.net.*;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.filesystem.File;
for (var i:Number=1; i<=5; i++)
{
    this["ads_box_" + i].photo_box.alpha = 0;
}
LocalCacheSettings.WORKING_DIRECTORY = File.applicationStorageDirectory;
var currentImageCount:uint = 1;
var pic_loader:Loader;
loadImage();
function loadImage():void
{
    NetClassFactory.initialize( LocalCacheLoader, LocalCacheURLLoader, LocalCacheNetStream );
    pic_loader = NetClassFactory.createLoader();
    pic_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, _onComplete );
    var pic_string:String = "http://localhost/Pics/" + String(currentImageCount) + ".jpg";
    pic_loader.load( new URLRequest(pic_string));
}

function _onComplete(e:Event):void
{
    var new_pic_mc:Sprite= new Sprite();
    new_pic_mc.addChild(pic_loader);
    new_pic_mc.width = new_pic_mc.height = 90;
    this["ads_box_" + currentImageCount].photo_box.addChild(new_pic_mc);
    this["ads_box_" + currentImageCount].photo_box.alpha = 1;
    pic_loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, _onComplete );
    if (currentImageCount < 5)
    {
        currentImageCount++;
        loadImage();
    }
    else
    {
        pic_loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, _onComplete);
    }
}
```